# Notation for permutations of function composition

Tags: functions, notation, function-and-relation-composition

Given a set of functions $F$ of which all are functions in $X \to X$, where certain functions, say $a, b \in F$ can be composed together:  $a(b(x)) = (a \circ b)(x)$. What is the notation for the set of all possible permutations of compositions of functions in $F$?

For example, say $F = \{a, b\}$ where $a, b : X \to X$, all the possible permutations of compositions of functions in $F$ are:

$(a \circ a)(x)$

$(a \circ b)(x)$

$(b \circ a)(x)$

$(b \circ b)(x)$

How would the set of the above be expressed in terms of $F$ *in general*? Should I not be expressing these functions as a set?

Comment: You could write $\{ f \circ g \mid f,g \in F \}$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm looking for a general notation. My example was to simplify the example permutation set but the cardinality of $F$ is undefined and may be arbitrarily large.

Comment: So you don't allow $a \circ a \circ a$ in your set?

Comment: @JairTaylor My mistake I was initially thinking of a fixed sample size of $|F|$ but yes I do allow $a \circ a \circ a$

Answer (score 1):

Note, you haven't provided all possible compositions, since there's also $aba$ and $abaaabbbaba$. Confusingly, the mathematical literature calls these "words".

You could use the [Kleene star notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) (in your case, $F^*$ ) to describe all possible words you can make, and interpret the words as compositions.

By the way, since function composition is associative, this structure forms a semigroup.

Comment: It's even a monoid, since we have the identity arrow.
Oh, my. It's a category.